# Function not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hello again my function questionAnswer is not working at all.It is suppose tip off the switch command. I used this website for help. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

```js
var keyword1 = "how are"
var keyword2 =  "what are" 
var keyword3 = "creator"
var keyword4 = "why"
var keyword5 = "how did"
var keyword6 = "Where were"
var keyword7 = "what do"
var keyword8 = "color"
var keyword9 = "Bye" 
var keyword10 = "animal"
var keyword11 = "Hello"

var robotAnswer1 = "Good"
var robotAnswer2 = "I am the new Lego “Dames” droid 7.0. I am the newest and most  advanced robot in this century!"
var robotAnswer3 = "My creator is James Day, I was programmed by Emanuel “Kiwi Elefant” Rotible"
var robotAnswer4 = "I was made to inspire imagination and bring smiles!"
var robotAnswer5 = "I was created with state-of-the-art technology in a lab."
var robotAnswer6 = "In a lab at Lego’s Headquarters"
var robotAnswer7 = "I can talk, move listen, respond and can teach programming to kids"
var robotAnswer8 = "I do not know what you are trying to say" 
var robotAnswer9 = "I was made to inspire imagination and bring smiles"
var robotAnswer10 = "I was created with state-of-the-art technology in a lab"
var robotAnswer11 = "In a lab at lego's Headquarters"

function questionAnswer()  {
var text;
var questionAnswer = prompt(“Ask me a Question!”);
switch(questionAnswer) {
    case questionAnswer :
     text = "Excellent choice! Whatever you said is good for your soul.";
        break;
    case keyword1:
     text = robotAnswer1;
        break;
case keyword2:
     text = robotAnswer2;
        break;
case keyword3:
     text = robotAnswer3;
        break;
case keyword4: 
     text = robotAnswer4;
        break;
case keyword5: 
     text = robotAnswer5;
        break;
case keyword6:
     text = robotAnswer6;
        break;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 < script>
var keyword1 = "how are"
var keyword2 =  "what are" 
var keyword3 = "creator"
var keyword4 = "why"
var keyword5 = "how did"
var keyword6 = "Where were"
var keyword7 = "what do"
var keyword8 = "color"
var keyword9 = "Bye" 
var keyword10 = "animal"
var keyword11 = "Hello"

var robotAnswer1 = "Good"
var robotAnswer2 = "I am the new Lego “Dames” droid 7.0. I am the newest and most  advanced robot in this century!"
var robotAnswer3 = "My creator is James Day, I was programmed by Emanuel “Kiwi Elefant” Rotible"
var robotAnswer4 = "I was made to inspire imagination and bring smiles!"
var robotAnswer5 = "I was created with state-of-the-art technology in a lab."
var robotAnswer6 = "In a lab at Lego’s Headquarters"
var robotAnswer7 = "I can talk, move listen, respond and can teach programming to kids"
var robotAnswer8 = "I do not know what you are trying to say" 
var robotAnswer9 = "I was made to inspire imagination and bring smiles"
var robotAnswer10 = "I was created with state-of-the-art technology in a lab"
var robotAnswer11 = "In a lab at lego's Headquarters"

function questionAnswer()  {
var text;
var questionAnswer = prompt(“Ask me a Question!”);
switch(questionAnswer) {
    case questionAnswer :
     text = "Excellent choice! Whatever you said is good for your soul.";
        break;
    case keyword1:
     text = robotAnswer1;
        break;
case keyword2:
     text = robotAnswer2;
        break;
case keyword3:
     text = robotAnswer3;
        break;
case keyword4: 
     text = robotAnswer4;
        break;
case keyword5: 
     text = robotAnswer5;
        break;
case keyword6:
     text = robotAnswer6;
        break;
}
</head>
<body>
  <title> Robot interaction </Title>
    <base target="_top">
   <img class="irc_mi" style="margin-top: 2px;" src="http://engineering.missouri.edu/wp-content/uploads/Lego-Robot.jpeg" width="304" height="390">

  </script>
</form>

</body>


<button onclick ="questionAnswer();">Ask</button>
</script>
 





<body>
<script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked console? There is an issue in your code `case :`.

Comment: I think you'll find your problem lies with the empty case, 
...case : text = "Excelle..., have you tried debugging it with devtools?

Comment: And why have a form in the HEAD?

Comment: Sorry........I'll try that.

Comment: And instead of using case, have `keywords = { "how are you": "Good",  "what are you":"I am the new....\"Dames\".....", ..... }` so you can use `keywords[answer]` instead

Comment: why are you submitting the form to asp page when it looks like your script is doing all the stuff? And prompt and form looks like redundant?

Comment: @mplungjan explain plz!

Comment: Too much going on here. Fix some more and ask some more. You need to put the text somewhere too

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `function questionAnswer  {` with `function questionAnswer () {`

Second, you're missing a `}` closure in the end of `function questionAnswer`

Third, replace all `“` instances with `"` or `'`

Forth, the first case, `case :` is empty - put some value in there.

Fifth, as mplungjan suggested, put the form in the body.

As a general practice, please test your html with a debugger, for example, in Chrome, press F12 and refresh the page to see if there are any errors.

Hope this helps

Comment: and sixth, since text is not used anywhere the "computed" value will simply be discarded. No output at the moment.

Comment: Good point @Thomas, let us assume that the code's logic is to be continued.

Comment: You're very welcome @Manuela Rugemintwaza, please mark my answer accepted if you find it useful